# QGIS - Determine percentage of coverage of buffer for census tracts

Tags: buffer

I have a census tract shapefile for the state of South Dakota. I have providers plotted with a 40 mile radius buffer. I am trying to determine what percent of each census tract is covered by any part of the buffer. How can I do this?

Comment: This sounds like it is a simple process of running intersects and doing some field calculations. However, to make your question easier to follow / answer - could you please add some additional information: What software are you using? Do you have a picture of the data? I am not familiar with census tracts and how they look. Do these tracts overlap each other? etc... the more information you provide the better the responses will be.

Comment: The census tracts do not overlap each other. Are you familiar with county shapefiles? It would be the same process as the census tract I would think. I know it sounds like an easy process, I just can't figure it out for the life of me. So, if I have a county shapefile with 16 counties and have plotted 300 providers with 40 mile radius buffers. I want to know the area that is covered inside of the buffers. I have the area in ft already added to the attribute table for the census tract file. I am using QGIS 3.10 A Coruna.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you all for your responses. Much appreciated.